# How to customize ActionBar background image?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to use an image as a background of my ActionBar, like this (shown by red rectangle):
[image],

so I modified some files like these.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.CustomActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_img</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
```

On Android 4.4.2, I don't see any background image. Just the standard ActionBar. How to properly customize its image?

Comment: I think you can use Toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/test"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);             
        getWindow().getDecorView()
                .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    }


}
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use CollapsingToolbarLayout. For example, here https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

If you don't need scroll animation, you can use same scroll flag

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a custom toolbar my self as below.

1- in styles.xml

```
     <!--No Action Bar-->
        <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        </style>
 <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"/>
```

2- in android manifest use the style

```
<application
        android:name=".base.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</application>
```

3- create a custom toolbar layout under res/layout and put your element between the toolbar tags like linear layout, images and ...

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

4- use the tool bar inside your layout like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>




</FrameLayout>
```

hope this helps